# How can I install a GUI in Ubuntu 16.04 server edition?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gui

First I'm going to say that I'm quite new to Linux and I want to do this for learning purposes.

So what are the steps necessary to install a GUI (probably a window manager, a display/login manager, a desktop environment and possibly more?) in Ubuntu 16.04 Server Edition that I've installed inside VirtualBox?

Also, what are the options that I have when installing the aforementioned components?

Answer (score 5):

You can install the `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage that will install all the bells and whistles of GUI for you (as it's dependencies and the dependencies of dependencies and so on):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

`ubuntu-desktop` will install the following:

```
Window-manager: Compiz
Display-manager: LightDM
Desktop Environment: Unity
```

There are also many other `*-desktop` metapackages (e.g. `xubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop` etc) with different options for WM, DM, SE and others. You can also install them separately if you want.